# Opening an excel file from javascript and passing parameters

Tags: javascript, xls

Is it possible from JavaScript to open up an excel file (either locally or downloading it from server) but passing in parameters?

i.e. have a link with `href="/somefilename.xls?some-parameter"`

And as excel is opening up the file, it passes on the parameter to a VBA module.

The idea is that when I pass 'some-parameter', the bit of VBA code takes the argument and uses the parameter to do further processing.

Comment: Well first of all, start learning about how to reverse engineer the XLS format.

Comment: Do you have a good reason as to why you would down-vote me? "First of all...?" Do you have anything else to say apart from "first of all"? ... Is there "second of all?" or that's all you have to say "learn about how to reverse engineer the XLS format" ... WHY would I want to learn to reverse engineer XLS format when there is no NEED for me to reverse engineer. I require an answer to a very succinct question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.

- Generate an xlsx file on server side with builtinDocumentProperties(title, comment...) or advanced method is use CustomXMLParts.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197172.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.customxmlparts.aspx

- You can open it from the browser with custom protocol and command line.

https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/201145908-How-to-launch-external-applications-using-custom-protocols-rock-instead-of-http-

There is a method how can you access to command line parameters with vba.

http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_vba-getcommandline/